# .net core 2.0 JWT token

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.0, jwt

I have a web Api built with .net core 2.0 and a mobile app built with xamarin. To login the mobile app make a call to the web api by passing (username and password). If the credentials are valid web Api provide back a JWT token. The mobile app has a feature that keep the user logged in even when you close the app, like (facebook, Instagram etc...).

The question are these:

1. How to keep the JWT token valid until the user is logged-In in the
   app without ask him/her again the login credentials to give him/her
   another valid JWT token?
2. How to make the JWT token invalid after the user decide to logout
   from the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to keep the JWT token valid until the user is logged-In in the app
> without ask him/her again the login credentials to give him/her
> another valid JWT token?

You can set a token expiry date and keep track of that.

> How to make the JWT token invalid after the user decide to logout from the app?

- If you keep the expiry time short and keep refreshing the token expiry until the user logs out.
- You can save some kind of blacklist of invalid tokens so you can validate against that.

**Update:**

The JWT consists of the Header, Payload and Signature. You can read all about it [here](https://jwt.io/introduction/) In the payload you can set an claim called: "exp".

> [The docs:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4)
> The "exp" (expiration time) claim identifies the expiration time on
> or after which the JWT MUST NOT be accepted for processing.  The
> processing of the "exp" claim requires that the current date/time
> MUST be before the expiration date/time listed in the "exp" claim.

Also, while researching to clarify my answer I found this SO answer: [JSON Web Token expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46031536/3378621).

Comment: By saying "You can set a token expiry date and keep track of that." you mean refresh token?

Answer (score 0):

```
 // This code tested with dotnet core 2.1 ( WebApi + Jwt )  with sample structure
```

//Add One class Auth to your project

```
public static class Auth
{
    private static string salt = "jnyanendra_sethi"; // u can chose any key satisfying the length 
    private static int timeoutInMinute = 1;
    private static string _issuer = "http://localhost:5000";
    private static string _audience = "http://localhost:5000";

    //Generate Token
    public static string GenerateToken(Customer customer, List<SupplierInfo> lstSpplierInfo)
    {
        var securitykey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt));
        var credential = new SigningCredentials(securitykey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        // var suppliers = any json string e.g. [{"SupplierId":1001,"SupplierName":"RateHawk"},{"SupplierId":1002,"SupplierName":"Hotelbeds"}]
        var suppliers = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstSpplierInfo);//"ur json object to store in claim";
        var claims = new List<Claim> {
           new Claim("CustomerName", customer.CustomerName),
           new Claim("Suppliers",suppliers )
       };

        var mytoken = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer: _issuer, audience: _audience,
            claims: claims, notBefore: DateTime.Now, expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeoutInMinute), signingCredentials: credential);
        var tokenValue = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(mytoken);
        return tokenValue;
    }

    //Validate token

    public static void ValidateJwtToken(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var securitykey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt));
        var credential = new SigningCredentials(securitykey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var tokenParam = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = _issuer,
            ValidAudience = _audience,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = credential.Key,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeoutInMinute)
        };

        services.AddAuthentication(
            options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(
            options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenParam;
            });

    }
}
```

---

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HotelController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet("Search")]
    public SearchReponse Search()// u can take search parameters for input
    {
        // based on apikey or username, call db for first time
        // get customername / supplierinfo from db
        Customer customer = new Customer() { CustomerId = "CUS001", CustomerName = "TestCust" };// dummy
        if (customer == null)
        {
            this.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return new SearchReponse()
            {
                ErrorInfo = new ErrorInfo()
                {
                    Code = "0",
                    Description = "No Customer Found"
                }
            };
        }

        string token = Auth.GenerateToken(customer, GetDummyDataToStoreInClaim());

        SearchReponse reponse = new SearchReponse()
        {
            GeneralInfo = new GeneralInfo()
            {
                Token = token,
                Duration = 0
            },
            Hotels = "Hotels Data",
        };
        return reponse;
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("Get/{id}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
    {//// Getting the data stored in claim that required for further process
        var CustomerName = HttpContext.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault().Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "CustomerName").Value;
        var strSuppliers = HttpContext.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault().Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "Suppliers").Value;
        return CustomerName;
    }
}
```

---

Models I have used:

```
 public class SearchReponse
{
    public GeneralInfo GeneralInfo { get; set; }
    public ErrorInfo ErrorInfo { get; set; }
    public string Hotels { get; set; }
}
public class GeneralInfo
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public long Duration { get; set; }
}
public class ErrorInfo
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

---

In Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.ValidateJwtToken();
        services.AddAuthorization(Options => {
            Options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

--